# How to solve $100^{63}$ mod 63

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am trying to solve this question but not able to figure out how to approach it.

$100^{63} \mod\ {63}$

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$100\equiv37 \mod 63$$
$$100^2\equiv46 \mod 63$$
$$100^3\equiv1 \mod 63$$
$$100^4\equiv37 \mod 63$$

**Note:**
I don't know much about Modular arithmetic but I consulted Wolfram Alpha, and found this

Comment: One of the many branches of my ignorance !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici So, you've reached your "up"voting limit?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here ! What is the *"up"voting limit* ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh, So that wasn't you??

Comment: I have this tendency to upvote good hints, when I judge that a hint is better than a full answer. I'm sad to say some higher rep users think differently and answer everything they can. May be that's why they have higher rep?

Comment: @DigitalBrain. I am slow but I finally understood ! Yes, I upvoted the question to compensate for the downvote which came immediately. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$100^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{63}$

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle63=9\cdot7$ and $(7,9)=1$

$\displaystyle100\equiv1\pmod9$

$\displaystyle100\equiv2\pmod7,\implies100^3\equiv2^3\equiv1$

$\displaystyle\implies100^{\text{lcm}(1,3)}\equiv1\pmod{7\cdot9}$

---

Alternatively, using [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), $\displaystyle\lambda(63)=6\implies10^6\equiv1\pmod{63}$ as $(10,63)=1$

$\displaystyle\implies100^3=(10^2)^3=10^6\equiv1\pmod{63}$

In either case, $\displaystyle100^{3r}\equiv1\pmod{63}$ for any integer $r\ge0$

Comment: @Monica, How about this?